# cross distance in rapidminer give question mark

Tags: rapidminer

I am using rapidminer to compare the similarity between two sheets in same excel file using cross distance, as I want to compart one request will all referernce to return the similarity value by cosine similarity, the problem is the distance returns as question mark `?` without knowing the reason.

Process XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="8.2.001"> <context> <input/> <output/> <macros/> </context> <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" name="Process"> <parameter key="logverbosity" value="init"/> <parameter key="random_seed" value="2001"/> <parameter key="send_mail" value="never"/> <parameter key="notification_email" value=""/> <parameter key="process_duration_for_mail" value="30"/> <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/> <process expanded="true"> <operator activated="true" class="read_excel" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Read Excel" width="90" x="45" y="391"> <parameter key="excel_file" value="/Users/macbook/Desktop/ULS/Change Management in ULS/WASP_Requirements.xlsx"/> <parameter key="sheet_selection" value="sheet number"/> <parameter key="sheet_number" value="1"/> <parameter key="imported_cell_range" value="A1:B72"/> <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/> <parameter key="first_row_as_names" value="false"/> <list key="annotations"/> <parameter key="date_format" value=""/> <parameter key="time_zone" value="SYSTEM"/> <parameter key="locale" value="English (United States)"/> <parameter key="read_all_values_as_polynominal" value="false"/> <list key="data_set_meta_data_information"> <parameter key="0" value="A.true.polynominal.id"/> <parameter key="1" value="B.true.polynominal.attribute"/> </list> <parameter key="read_not_matching_values_as_missings" value="true"/> <parameter key="datamanagement" value="double_array"/> <parameter key="data_management" value="auto"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="remove_duplicates" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Remove Duplicates" width="90" x="45" y="493"> <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="all"/> <parameter key="attribute" value=""/> <parameter key="attributes" value=""/> <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/> <parameter key="value_type" value="attribute_value"/> <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/> <parameter key="except_value_type" value="time"/> <parameter key="block_type" value="attribute_block"/> <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/> <parameter key="except_block_type" value="value_matrix_row_start"/> <parameter key="invert_selection" value="false"/> <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="false"/> <parameter key="treat_missing_values_as_duplicates" value="false"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Set Role" width="90" x="179" y="391"> <parameter key="attribute_name" value="A"/> <parameter key="target_role" value="id"/> <list key="set_additional_roles"> <parameter key="B" value="regular"/> <parameter key="A" value="id"/> </list> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="nominal_to_text" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Nominal to Text" width="90" x="179" y="493"> <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="all"/> <parameter key="attribute" value=""/> <parameter key="attributes" value=""/> <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/> <parameter key="value_type" value="nominal"/> <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/> <parameter key="except_value_type" value="file_path"/> <parameter key="block_type" value="single_value"/> <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/> <parameter key="except_block_type" value="single_value"/> <parameter key="invert_selection" value="false"/> <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="false"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="text:process_document_from_data" compatibility="8.1.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Process Documents from Data" width="90" x="313" y="391"> <parameter key="create_word_vector" value="true"/> <parameter key="vector_creation" value="TF-IDF"/> <parameter key="add_meta_information" value="true"/> <parameter key="keep_text" value="true"/> <parameter key="prune_method" value="absolute"/> <parameter key="prune_below_percent" value="3.0"/> <parameter key="prune_above_percent" value="30.0"/> <parameter key="prune_below_absolute" value="2"/> <parameter key="prune_above_absolute" value="9999"/> <parameter key="prune_below_rank" value="0.05"/> <parameter key="prune_above_rank" value="0.95"/> <parameter key="datamanagement" value="double_sparse_array"/> <parameter key="data_management" value="auto"/> <parameter key="select_attributes_and_weights" value="false"/> <list key="specify_weights"> <parameter key="B" value="1.0"/> </list> <process expanded="true"> <operator activated="true" class="text:tokenize" compatibility="8.1.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Tokenize" width="90" x="112" y="34"> <parameter key="mode" value="linguistic tokens"/> <parameter key="characters" value=".:"/> <parameter key="language" value="English"/> <parameter key="max_token_length" value="3"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="text:filter_stopwords_english" compatibility="8.1.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Filter Stopwords (English)" width="90" x="112" y="136"/> <operator activated="true" class="text:transform_cases" compatibility="8.1.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Transform Cases" width="90" x="112" y="238"> <parameter key="transform_to" value="lower case"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="wordnet:open_wordnet_dictionary" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Open WordNet Dictionary" width="90" x="313" y="391"> <parameter key="resource_type" value="directory"/> <parameter key="directory" value="/Users/macbook/Downloads/WordNet-3.0/dict"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="wordnet:stem_wordnet" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Stem (WordNet)" width="90" x="313" y="238"> <parameter key="allow_ambiguity" value="true"/> <parameter key="keep_unmatched_stems" value="true"/> <parameter key="keep_unmatched_tokens" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_noun" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_verb" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_adjective" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_adverb" value="true"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="wordnet:find_synonym_wordnet" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Find Synonyms (WordNet)" width="90" x="447" y="238"> <parameter key="use_prefix" value="false"/> <parameter key="synset_word_prefix" value="syn:"/> <parameter key="maximum_recursion_depth" value="1"/> <parameter key="multiple_meanings_per_word_policy" value="Take only first meaning"/> <parameter key="multiple_synsets_policy" value="Take only first synset per meaning"/> <parameter key="multiple_synset_words_policy" value="Take only first synset word"/> <parameter key="concatenation" value="Concatenate result per synset"/> <parameter key="keep_original_tokens" value="true"/> <parameter key="keep_unmatched_tokens" value="true"/> <parameter key="take_ID_instead_of_words" value="false"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_noun" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_verb" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_adjective" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_adverb" value="true"/> </operator> <connect from_port="document" to_op="Tokenize" to_port="document"/> <connect from_op="Tokenize" from_port="document" to_op="Filter Stopwords (English)" to_port="document"/> <connect from_op="Filter Stopwords (English)" from_port="document" to_op="Transform Cases" to_port="document"/> <connect from_op="Transform Cases" from_port="document" to_op="Stem (WordNet)" to_port="document"/> <connect from_op="Open WordNet Dictionary" from_port="dictionary" to_op="Stem (WordNet)" to_port="dictionary"/> <connect from_op="Stem (WordNet)" from_port="document" to_op="Find Synonyms (WordNet)" to_port="document"/> <connect from_op="Stem (WordNet)" from_port="dictionary" to_op="Find Synonyms (WordNet)" to_port="dictionary"/> <connect from_op="Find Synonyms (WordNet)" from_port="document" to_port="document 1"/> <portSpacing port="source_document" spacing="0"/> <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/> <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/> </process> </operator> <operator activated="false" class="concurrency:k_means" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Clustering" width="90" x="782" y="34"> <parameter key="add_cluster_attribute" value="true"/> <parameter key="add_as_label" value="false"/> <parameter key="remove_unlabeled" value="false"/> <parameter key="k" value="40"/> <parameter key="max_runs" value="10"/> <parameter key="determine_good_start_values" value="true"/> <parameter key="measure_types" value="BregmanDivergences"/> <parameter key="mixed_measure" value="MixedEuclideanDistance"/> <parameter key="nominal_measure" value="NominalDistance"/> <parameter key="numerical_measure" value="EuclideanDistance"/> <parameter key="divergence" value="SquaredEuclideanDistance"/> <parameter key="kernel_type" value="radial"/> <parameter key="kernel_gamma" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_sigma1" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_sigma2" value="0.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_sigma3" value="2.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_degree" value="3.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_shift" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_a" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_b" value="0.0"/> <parameter key="max_optimization_steps" value="100"/> <parameter key="use_local_random_seed" value="false"/> <parameter key="local_random_seed" value="1992"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="read_excel" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Read Excel (2)" width="90" x="45" y="85"> <parameter key="excel_file" value="/Users/macbook/Desktop/ULS/Change Management in ULS/WASP_Requirements.xlsx"/> <parameter key="sheet_selection" value="sheet number"/> <parameter key="sheet_number" value="2"/> <parameter key="imported_cell_range" value="A1:B1"/> <parameter key="encoding" value="SYSTEM"/> <parameter key="first_row_as_names" value="false"/> <list key="annotations"/> <parameter key="date_format" value=""/> <parameter key="time_zone" value="SYSTEM"/> <parameter key="locale" value="English (United States)"/> <parameter key="read_all_values_as_polynominal" value="false"/> <list key="data_set_meta_data_information"> <parameter key="0" value="A.true.polynominal.id"/> <parameter key="1" value="B.true.polynominal.attribute"/> </list> <parameter key="read_not_matching_values_as_missings" value="true"/> <parameter key="datamanagement" value="double_array"/> <parameter key="data_management" value="auto"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="remove_duplicates" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Remove Duplicates (2)" width="90" x="45" y="187"> <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="all"/> <parameter key="attribute" value=""/> <parameter key="attributes" value=""/> <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/> <parameter key="value_type" value="attribute_value"/> <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/> <parameter key="except_value_type" value="time"/> <parameter key="block_type" value="attribute_block"/> <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/> <parameter key="except_block_type" value="value_matrix_row_start"/> <parameter key="invert_selection" value="false"/> <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="false"/> <parameter key="treat_missing_values_as_duplicates" value="false"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Set Role (2)" width="90" x="179" y="85"> <parameter key="attribute_name" value="A"/> <parameter key="target_role" value="id"/> <list key="set_additional_roles"> <parameter key="B" value="regular"/> <parameter key="A" value="id"/> </list> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="nominal_to_text" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Nominal to Text (2)" width="90" x="179" y="187"> <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="all"/> <parameter key="attribute" value=""/> <parameter key="attributes" value=""/> <parameter key="use_except_expression" value="false"/> <parameter key="value_type" value="nominal"/> <parameter key="use_value_type_exception" value="false"/> <parameter key="except_value_type" value="file_path"/> <parameter key="block_type" value="single_value"/> <parameter key="use_block_type_exception" value="false"/> <parameter key="except_block_type" value="single_value"/> <parameter key="invert_selection" value="false"/> <parameter key="include_special_attributes" value="false"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="text:process_document_from_data" compatibility="8.1.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Process Documents from Data (2)" width="90" x="313" y="85"> <parameter key="create_word_vector" value="true"/> <parameter key="vector_creation" value="TF-IDF"/> <parameter key="add_meta_information" value="true"/> <parameter key="keep_text" value="true"/> <parameter key="prune_method" value="absolute"/> <parameter key="prune_below_percent" value="3.0"/> <parameter key="prune_above_percent" value="30.0"/> <parameter key="prune_below_absolute" value="2"/> <parameter key="prune_above_absolute" value="9999"/> <parameter key="prune_below_rank" value="0.05"/> <parameter key="prune_above_rank" value="0.95"/> <parameter key="datamanagement" value="double_sparse_array"/> <parameter key="data_management" value="auto"/> <parameter key="select_attributes_and_weights" value="false"/> <list key="specify_weights"> <parameter key="B" value="1.0"/> </list> <process expanded="true"> <operator activated="true" class="text:tokenize" compatibility="8.1.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Tokenize (2)" width="90" x="112" y="34"> <parameter key="mode" value="linguistic tokens"/> <parameter key="characters" value=".:"/> <parameter key="language" value="English"/> <parameter key="max_token_length" value="3"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="text:filter_stopwords_english" compatibility="8.1.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Filter Stopwords (2)" width="90" x="112" y="136"/> <operator activated="true" class="text:transform_cases" compatibility="8.1.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Transform Cases (2)" width="90" x="112" y="238"> <parameter key="transform_to" value="lower case"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="wordnet:open_wordnet_dictionary" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Open WordNet Dictionary (2)" width="90" x="313" y="391"> <parameter key="resource_type" value="directory"/> <parameter key="directory" value="/Users/macbook/Downloads/WordNet-3.0/dict"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="wordnet:stem_wordnet" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Stem (2)" width="90" x="313" y="238"> <parameter key="allow_ambiguity" value="true"/> <parameter key="keep_unmatched_stems" value="true"/> <parameter key="keep_unmatched_tokens" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_noun" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_verb" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_adjective" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_adverb" value="true"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="wordnet:find_synonym_wordnet" compatibility="5.3.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Find Synonyms (2)" width="90" x="447" y="238"> <parameter key="use_prefix" value="false"/> <parameter key="synset_word_prefix" value="syn:"/> <parameter key="maximum_recursion_depth" value="1"/> <parameter key="multiple_meanings_per_word_policy" value="Take only first meaning"/> <parameter key="multiple_synsets_policy" value="Take only first synset per meaning"/> <parameter key="multiple_synset_words_policy" value="Take only first synset word"/> <parameter key="concatenation" value="Concatenate result per synset"/> <parameter key="keep_original_tokens" value="true"/> <parameter key="keep_unmatched_tokens" value="true"/> <parameter key="take_ID_instead_of_words" value="false"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_noun" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_verb" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_adjective" value="true"/> <parameter key="work_on_type_adverb" value="true"/> </operator> <connect from_port="document" to_op="Tokenize (2)" to_port="document"/> <connect from_op="Tokenize (2)" from_port="document" to_op="Filter Stopwords (2)" to_port="document"/> <connect from_op="Filter Stopwords (2)" from_port="document" to_op="Transform Cases (2)" to_port="document"/> <connect from_op="Transform Cases (2)" from_port="document" to_op="Stem (2)" to_port="document"/> <connect from_op="Open WordNet Dictionary (2)" from_port="dictionary" to_op="Stem (2)" to_port="dictionary"/> <connect from_op="Stem (2)" from_port="document" to_op="Find Synonyms (2)" to_port="document"/> <connect from_op="Stem (2)" from_port="dictionary" to_op="Find Synonyms (2)" to_port="dictionary"/> <connect from_op="Find Synonyms (2)" from_port="document" to_port="document 1"/> <portSpacing port="source_document" spacing="0"/> <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/> <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/> </process> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="multiply" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Multiply" width="90" x="447" y="85"/> <operator activated="true" class="order_attributes" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Reorder Attributes" width="90" x="447" y="238"> <parameter key="sort_mode" value="reference data"/> <parameter key="attribute_ordering" value=""/> <parameter key="use_regular_expressions" value="false"/> <parameter key="handle_unmatched" value="append"/> <parameter key="sort_direction" value="ascending"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="multiply" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Multiply (2)" width="90" x="581" y="340"/> <operator activated="true" class="order_attributes" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Reorder Attributes (2)" width="90" x="581" y="238"> <parameter key="sort_mode" value="reference data"/> <parameter key="attribute_ordering" value=""/> <parameter key="use_regular_expressions" value="false"/> <parameter key="handle_unmatched" value="append"/> <parameter key="sort_direction" value="ascending"/> </operator> <operator activated="true" class="cross_distances" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="103" name="Cross Distances" width="90" x="715" y="238"> <parameter key="measure_types" value="NumericalMeasures"/> <parameter key="mixed_measure" value="MixedEuclideanDistance"/> <parameter key="nominal_measure" value="SimpleMatchingSimilarity"/> <parameter key="numerical_measure" value="CosineSimilarity"/> <parameter key="divergence" value="GeneralizedIDivergence"/> <parameter key="kernel_type" value="radial"/> <parameter key="kernel_gamma" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_sigma1" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_sigma2" value="0.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_sigma3" value="2.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_degree" value="3.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_shift" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_a" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_b" value="0.0"/> <parameter key="only_top_k" value="false"/> <parameter key="k" value="10"/> <parameter key="search_for" value="nearest"/> <parameter key="compute_similarities" value="true"/> </operator> <operator activated="false" class="data_to_similarity" compatibility="8.2.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Data to Similarity" width="90" x="648" y="34"> <parameter key="measure_types" value="NumericalMeasures"/> <parameter key="mixed_measure" value="MixedEuclideanDistance"/> <parameter key="nominal_measure" value="NominalDistance"/> <parameter key="numerical_measure" value="CosineSimilarity"/> <parameter key="divergence" value="GeneralizedIDivergence"/> <parameter key="kernel_type" value="radial"/> <parameter key="kernel_gamma" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_sigma1" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_sigma2" value="0.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_sigma3" value="2.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_degree" value="3.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_shift" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_a" value="1.0"/> <parameter key="kernel_b" value="0.0"/> </operator> <connect from_op="Read Excel" from_port="output" to_op="Remove Duplicates" to_port="example set input"/> <connect from_op="Remove Duplicates" from_port="example set output" to_op="Set Role" to_port="example set input"/> <connect from_op="Set Role" from_port="example set output" to_op="Nominal to Text" to_port="example set input"/> <connect from_op="Nominal to Text" from_port="example set output" to_op="Process Documents from Data" to_port="example set"/> <connect from_op="Process Documents from Data" from_port="example set" to_op="Reorder Attributes" to_port="example set input"/> <connect from_op="Read Excel (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Remove Duplicates (2)" to_port="example set input"/> <connect from_op="Remove Duplicates (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Set Role (2)" to_port="example set input"/> <connect from_op="Set Role (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Nominal to Text (2)" to_port="example set input"/> <connect from_op="Nominal to Text (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Process Documents from Data (2)" to_port="example set"/> <connect from_op="Process Documents from Data (2)" from_port="example set" to_op="Multiply" to_port="input"/> <connect from_op="Multiply" from_port="output 1" to_op="Reorder Attributes (2)" to_port="example set input"/> <connect from_op="Multiply" from_port="output 2" to_op="Reorder Attributes" to_port="reference_data"/> <connect from_op="Reorder Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_op="Multiply (2)" to_port="input"/> <connect from_op="Multiply (2)" from_port="output 1" to_op="Reorder Attributes (2)" to_port="reference_data"/> <connect from_op="Multiply (2)" from_port="output 2" to_op="Cross Distances" to_port="reference set"/> <connect from_op="Reorder Attributes (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Cross Distances" to_port="request set"/> <connect from_op="Cross Distances" from_port="result set" to_port="result 1"/> <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/> <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/> <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/> <description align="center" color="gray" colored="true" height="163" resized="true" width="142" x="28" y="320">Read Requirements Document</description> <description align="center" color="gray" colored="true" height="147" resized="true" width="126" x="30" y="14">Read Requirements Change Requests</description> </process> </operator> </process>
```

Process Overview:
[image]

Comment: I edited your question to make the xml of the process visible.

Answer (score 0):

the most likely reason for that what be, that you have infinite values somewhere in your data. For them the cosine distance is not defined, thus you get a "?" aka missing value in your result.

If this is the case you can use the `Replace Infinite Values` operator before the calculation.